# An idiomatic Python version of Ruby code with a while loop that tests a statement?

Tags: python, ruby

The following code Ruby code will iterate the source string and produce a list of the cumulative words delimited by a '.' character, other than those after the last '.'.

For example, give a source string of 'Company.Dept.Group.Team' the result will be ...
["Company.Dept.Group", "Company.Dept", "Company"]

Given that a while loop in Python (I believe) will test only an expression and not a statement as shown below, how would one best write this in idiomatic Python?

```
#ruby
source = 'Company.Dept.Group.Team'
results = []

temp = source.clone
while (i = temp.rindex('.'))  # test statement not supported in Python?
  temp = temp[0...i]
  results << temp
end

p results   # >> ["Company.Dept.Group", "Company.Dept", "Company"]
```

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, Python does not allow assigments in if conditions... which could be such handy thing sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python idiom is something like this:

```
while True:
    i = temp.rindex('.')
    if not i:
        break
    ...
```

Comment: `rindex` raises a ValueError, though, so this won't work as written.

Comment: Also, `if not i` would be wrong anyway because `0` is a valid position in the string. `rfind()` would return `-1` if it couldn't find the string.

Comment: I marked this as the answer, because you were first to mention using 'while True:' as the Python idiomatic equivalent of a Ruby while loop that tests a statement.  I think the exact code I might use is rfind() instead of rindex(), and then test for -1 to break on.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> source = 'Company.Dept.Group.Team'
>>> last = []
>>> [last.append(s) or '.'.join(last) for s in source.split('.')[:-1]]
['Company', 'Company.Dept', 'Company.Dept.Group']
```

Comment: A list comprehension with side effects?  Usually, this isn't excatly considered "idiomatic Python".

Answer (score 1):

If you get used to Python you see list comprehensions and iterators/generators everywhere!

Python could be

```
source = 'Company.Dept.Group.Team'

# generate substrings
temp = source.split(".")
results = [".".join(temp[:i+1]) for i,s in enumerate(temp)]

# pop the team (alternatively slice the team out above)
results.pop()

# reverse results
result.reverse()

print result # should yield ["Company.Dept.Group", "Company.Dept", "Company"]
```

but most probably there are more idiomatic solutions ...

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this in general, I'd probably do:

```
source = 'Company.Dept.Group.Team'
split_source = source.split('.')
results = ['.'.join(split_source[0:x]) for x in xrange(len(split_source) - 1, 0, -1)]
print results
```

A literal translation would be more like:

```
source = 'Company.Dept.Group.Team'

temp = source
results = []
while True:
    i = temp.rfind('.')
    if i < 0:
        break
    temp = temp[0:i]
    results.append(temp)

print results
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
source = 'Company.Dept.Group.Team'

temp = source
results = []
try:
    while True:
        temp = temp[0:temp.rindex('.')]
        results.append(temp)
except ValueError:
    pass
print results
```

Or:

```
source = 'Company.Dept.Group.Team'

temp = source
results = []
i = temp.rfind('.')
while i > 0:
    temp = temp[0:i]
    results.append(temp)
    i = temp.rfind('.')

print results
```

As you point out, the fact that you cannot treat assignment as an expression makes these cases a bit inelegant. I think the former cases(s) - i.e. "while True" - are more common than the last one.

For more background, this post looks pretty good: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
>>> import re
>>> source = 'Company.Dept.Group.Team'
>>> results = [source[:m.start()] for m in re.finditer(r"\.", source)]
>>> results
['Company', 'Company.Dept', 'Company.Dept.Group']
```

(use `reversed(results)` if you want the order to be reversed).

A more or less literal translation of your code into Python would be

```
source = 'Company.Dept.Group.Team'
results = []
temp = source

while True:
    try:
        i = temp.rindex('.')
        temp = temp[:i]    
        results.append(temp)
    except ValueError:
        break
print(results)
```